# animation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to render an animation using javascript that displays a div lifting up and another div sliding behind that div resembling a letter going inside an envelope. can it be done using jquery?

Comment: Yes it can be done. You should probably try doing it first, and ask here if you are not successful in your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly easy using `.slideUp` and/or `.slideDown`, but you should give us some html/css code to see how your divs look, so that we can give you a deep answer.